# Memory leaks in iOS7 but not iOS6.1 Foundation, UIKit, Quartzcore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in the iOS SDK but am posting here for clarification as I'm not totally sure how to interpret instruments.

I have an app which shows a memory leak on launch ONLY when on iOS7.  I have tried removing the classes on all of my viewcontrollers so that the only code executing should be AppDelegate and main.m but the leaks don't disappear.  Is this a SDK bug?  Should I be submitting a bugreport?

iOS6:
[image: iOS6.1]

iOS7:
[image: 7 1]
[image: 7 2]
[image: 7 3]
[image: 7 4]

Comment: May be a leak, maybe not.  Could be pointer hiding.  Feel free to submit a bug and attach a copy of your compiled binary or, better yet, source of a minimal example.  Include clear steps to reproduce and a link to this question.

Comment: Yeh I will do when I get back to the office tomorrow.  Do you think this is something worth spending a lot of time on?  My interpretation tells me that ~30kb has been allocated and is now unreachable.  On a device with 512mb+ ram that's no biggy right?  And does the light grey text in the image represent the class that is causing the error?  Finally :p 'pointer hiding', does that mean a false positive?